# Error plotting symbolic variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, convolution, symbolic-math

I am trying to learn fourier transform from book"signals and systems laboratory with matlab alex palamides"

On page 312, following code is given which demonstrates that convolution can be implemented by multiplying the fourier transforms of two signals and then taking the inverse fourier of product

```
syms t w
x1=heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-2);
x2=heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-4);
X1=fourier(x1,w);
X2=fourier(x2,w);
right=ifourier(X1*X2,t)
ezplot(right)
```

I tried MATLAB 2019 and MATLAB 2020 but i get same problem in both

Actually When i try to run above code in my MATLAB i don't get output like the one in book, instead i get following error

```
Error using inlineeval (line 14)
Error in inline expression ==> (t.*pi.*sign(t) + fourier(cos(2.*w)./w.^2, w, -t) +
fourier(cos(4.*w)./w.^2, w, -t) - fourier(cos(6.*w)./w.^2, w, -t) - fourier(sin(2.*w)./w.^2, w,
-t).*1i - fourier(sin(4.*w)./w.^2, w, -t).*1i + fourier(sin(6.*w)./w.^2, w, -t).*1i)./(2.*pi)
 Undefined function 'fourier' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in inline/feval (line 33)
        INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr, INLINE_OBJ_.expr);

Error in ezplotfeval (line 53)
    z = feval(f,x(1),y(1));

Error in ezplot>ezimplicit (line 271)
    u = ezplotfeval(f, X, Y);

Error in ezplot (line 167)
                hp = ezimplicit(cax, f{1}, vars, labels, args{:});

Error in sym/ezplot (line 66)
   h = ezplot(fhandle(f)); %#ok<EZPLT>

Error in Untitled (line 7)
ezplot(right)
```

Snapshot of book page also attached here[image]

Comment: It seems you forgot to define `fourier`, is that maybe defined somewhere earlier in that book?

Comment: Right, so this is indeed weird, as `fourier` should be in the symbolic toolbox by default. What MATLAB version is mentioned in the book? There's a note in the documentation on `ezplot`  that it's no longer recommended, so it might be something changed there.

Comment: Did you have all the required toolboxes installed?

Comment: @Miscellaneous , yes

Comment: @flawr Fourier is built in command/function of MATLAB

Comment: @Adriaan this book was originally published somewhere near 2010 so MATLAB version will some one before 2011, i am not able to find MATLAB version number in book

Comment: @Adriaan yes i know that ezplot command is not recommended and i tried to use another suggested function, fplot, this time my plot window opens up but there is no graph in it, and as per book there should be a hat like graph in plot window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the same question on [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/462119-error-while-executing-textbook-matlab-code). The solution as posted by
[Walter Roberson](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/434782) is to [rewrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/rewrite.html) `X1*X2` in terms of `exp` before taking the [inverse fourier transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.ifourier.html). Quoting from MATLAB Answers:

> In your release of MATLAB, ezplot() was not compatible with plotting symbolic expressions, and fplot() had to be used instead.
> However, the `ifourier()` is giving unusable results that neither `ezplot()` nor `fplot()` can use.
> The work-around, valid from R2012a, is:
>
> ```
> right = ifourier( rewrite(X1*X2, 'exp'), t);
> fplot(right, [0 8])
> ```

**Result (on R2021b):**

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like matlab cannot [transform the function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.ifourier.html?s_tid=doc_ta#buoof5p-1)  `X1*X2`, so it returns the inverse fourier transform as an unevaluated call to fourier.

```
>> right

right =
 
(pi*t*sign(t) + fourier(cos(2*w)/w^2, w, -t) + fourier(cos(4*w)/w^2, w, -t) - fourier(cos(6*w)/w^2, w, -t) - fourier(sin(2*w)/w^2, w, -t)*1i - fourier(sin(4*w)/w^2, w, -t)*1i + fourier(sin(6*w)/w^2, w, -t)*1i)/(2*pi)
```

`ezplot`, or `fplot` can not plot a expression like this.

Comment: So you mean,we are stuck at end of a one way street? There is no way out?