# Why i am getting blank graph?How can i solve this issue?

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, symbolic-math

I am trying to plot symbolic variable in MATLAB, for which I have used the same strategy that is available in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72024277/error-plotting-symbolic-variable-in-matlab).

This is my code, which outputs a blank graph:

```
syms t w
x=exp(-t^2)
h=exp(-t)*heaviside(t)+exp(t)*heaviside(-t)
X=fourier(x,w);
H=fourier(h,w);
right=ifourier( rewrite(X*H, 'exp'),t)
fplot(right,[0 8])
```

How can I make the graph appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MATLAB `ifourier` function cannot compute the inverse Fourier transform of the product X*H.

Check that `X*H` returns:

```
X*H
```

[image]

Rewriting the expression does not change it at all:

```
rewrite(X*H, 'exp')
```

[image]

Either way, when computing the inverse Fourier transform:

```
right=ifourier( X*H,t)
```

[image]

Documentation on the [ifourier function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.ifourier.html) states that:

> If ifourier cannot transform the input, then it returns an unevaluated
> call to fourier.

Since it cannot evaluate explicitly the function, it cannot plot it.